# How to calculate mutual information between a phrase and a list of words

Tags: mutual-information

I am using this paper [Finding Semantic Orientation of Reviews Using
Unsupervised PMI Algorithm](https://www.ijsr.net/archive/v5i2/NOV161734.pdf)  to determine semantic orientation between a phrase and a list of words using pointwize mutual information.

For example : PMI(phrase, {"excellent", "Good"}).

My question is how Can I compute the PMI between the phrase and the list of words?

Thank you